# Modifying a file with sed using redirection

Tags: bash, sed

this works as I expected:

```
$ cat in
abc 123
$ sed -E -i .bk 's/[0-9]+/(&)/' in
$ cat in 
abc (123)
$ cat in.bk
abc 123
```

But not this:

```
$ cat in
abc 123
$ sed -E 's/[0-9]+/(&)/' in 
abc (123)
$ sed -E 's/[0-9]+/(&)/' in > in
$ cat in
```

How can I modify the above set of commands such that the last command returns, instead:

```
abc (123)
```

?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `-i` option?

Comment: How is that helpful?

Comment: It is not suppose to be helpfull. It's just a question, you have a command that works fine, why would you use another one?

Comment: Out of curiosity.

Comment: Shell will first interpret redirection, so since you want to overwrite the file with `>`, the shell will first create the file, or if it already exists, the shell will erase it's content. When `sed` tries to open the file, it is already empty. The GNU sed `-i` option doesn't write to the file itself, instead sed creates a copy of the file and at the end rename that copy. If you edit a very big file you can see the copy file created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -i -E 's/[0-9]+/(&)/' in
```

Alternatively,

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]+/(&)/' in | tee in
```

overwrites the file AND gives you the output on stdout.

Comment: OK, but I don't see why ... in > in does not overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** Modifying a file with `sed` using *redirection*.

**Answer:** obviously, the `-i` switch was added to `sed` for a reason. Just using *redirection* leaves you looking at a somewhat convoluted solution.

```
cat in | cat - | sed -E 's/[0-9]+/(&)/' > in
```

The following also work, but only if the input file contains a single line:

```
cat in | parallel 'echo {} | sed -E "s/[0-9]+/(&)/" > in'
```

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]+/(&)/' in | parallel 'echo {} >in'
```

**Explanation:**
The explanation is provided by Paulo in his comment to the question (redirection is interpreted before the command is executed). My workaround is to add a level of indirection between reading the file and writing back to it.